# I have two checkboxes that control the speed of an animation, and I need to combine these into one button that increments with each press

Tags: html, css

Currently I have two checkboxes that control the speed of an animated fan giving me four speeds (no checks = speed 0; each checkbox checked individually = speed 1 and 2; and both checked together = speed 3). Now I need it to be one button that cycles through each speed. I also need a second button that reverses the fan, but I can wory about that later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the solution you desire requires javascript, and so I would refer you straight away to the second example in the code snippet I provided. There is also the first code snippet to see what this would look like using CSS, although CSS by itself won't be able to keep track of how many times you have clicked, so the second you will not be able to get the animation to speed up/slow down again and again.

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#javascript");
myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Gets the current CSS style 
  const currentDuration = parseFloat(myDiv.style.animationDuration[0]);
  // Makes it faster by cutting the time to loop in half
  const newDuration = currentDuration/2;
  // Uses a string literal to change the CSS
  myDiv.style.animationDuration = `${newDuration}s`
})
```

```css
@keyframes myanimation {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

p {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: myanimation 4s infinite;
}

p:active {
  border: 10px solid black;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}

#javascript {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: myanimation infinite;
}
```

```html
CSS Solution (No memory)
<p>
</p>

JS Solution (With memory)
<!-- The styling you want to change must be in-line CSS for the Javascript to read it (To the best of my knowledge)-->
<div style="animation-duration: 4s" id="javascript">
</div>
```